# Can "external" javascript functions call "jQuery functions"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
(function ($) {  

    $(document).ready(function() { 
         test("hola","caracola");
    });

    function test(somevar1, somevar2)
    {
        alert(somevar1+ "" + somevar2);
    }

}(jQuery));

function atest2(somevar1, somevar2)
{
    test(somevar1+ "" + somevar2);
}
```

when executing test2 function the result is:

```
ReferenceError: test is not defined
```

My question is:

How can I call test2 to execute correctly jQuery's inner test function?

Thanks

Comment: You will have to define `test` outside of the anonymous function.

Comment: You can define `test()` outside of the jQuery load function, and still use it from within.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to export `test` to the global scope if you want to use it outside the anonymous function. That can be done in ths way:

```
(function ($) {  
    // ...
    function test(somevar1, somevar2) {
        alert(somevar1+ "" + somevar2);
    }
    window.test = test; // <-- This
}(jQuery));
```

The big advantage of this method over moving the function declaration outside the anonymous function is that `test` can still use local variables, which are only accessible from within the anonymous function.

Answer (score 2):

`test` is only defined in the anonymous function wrapped around it.

For the most part, function definitions should ALWAYS be outside of any anonymous functions. There are of course exceptions, but those only apply to people who know exactly what they're doing with closures.

Answer (score 0):

Look this is outside the onready function and then you can use it.

```
function test(somevar1, somevar2)
{
    alert(somevar1+ "" + somevar2);
}

(function ($) {  

    $(document).ready(function() { 
         test("hola","caracola");
    });

}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call the function using apply, that is calling test from the callee

```
(function ($) {  

    $(document).ready(function() {
         test.apply(this,["hola","caracola"]);
    });

    function test(somevar1, somevar2)
    {
        alert(somevar1+ "" + somevar2);
    }

}(jQuery));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AHSHP/4/)

Answer (score 0):

As stated by fellow members its clear that `test` function can be called if it is outside the anonymous function. This is necessary coz by defining `test` function inside anonymous function limit the **scope of `test` function**.Moreover, jquery is an awesome framwork for javascript , but after all its `javascript` so ne valid `javascript` snipplet wud work with jquery and vice-versa